# Sort by 3rd element of tuple, then group by first and assign rank

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to apache-spark and scala both, so i apologize if this is a trivial question.

I am trying to build a recommender system and have a RDD of the form (User,Product,Predicted Rating).

What I want to achieve :

Grouped by user, i want a list of products (sorted in descending order of rating) and assign a rank to the predictions based on this list (for each user). Can anyone tell me how i would be able to achieve this ?

The below code clearly doesn't work but that is what I am trying to achieve

```
val xyz = ratesAndPreds.map{case ((user,product),(r1,r2)) => (user,product,r2)}

val def = xyz.sortBy(_._3)

val abc = abc.groupByKey()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your definition of steps more or less converts to the identical scala code. Perhaps there is some specific problem?

Comment: @om-nom-nom no. no specific problem . i just don't know the following things :
1. how to sort by the 3rd element of the tuple.
2. once this is done, how to make the tuple of the form (U,(P,R)) so that i can use groupByKey() on it ? or if it's possible to group without doing that, then how to do that ?

Comment: @om-nom-nom using normal sortBy(_._3) gives this error " value sortBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, Double)]

Comment: Sounds like xyz needs to be converted to a List in order to use sortBy

Comment: @Gangstead could you tell me how I can convert it to a list and then sort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
val groupedByUser = xyz.groupBy(_._1)
val sortedProductsByUser = groupedByUser mapValues { triples =>
  // this is done for every user, for its list of (user, product, rating)
  // (yes, user is thus the same for all the elements of triples here)
  val sortedTriples = triples.sortBy(_._3) // assuming rating has an Ordering, e.g., it's an Int
  val keepOnlyProducts = sortedTriples.map(_._2)
  keepOnlyProducts
}
```

Comment: Yup ! This does work. Thanks. However, could you also tell me how to pass in a parameter to have the sort in descending order. And if possible , could you explain what mapValues exactly does ?

Comment: To sort in descending order, simply change the order in `sortBy`, for example by negating the argument: `-_._3`.
`mapValues` is like `map` but only the *values* part. So, keys are all preserved, and for each key, the corresponding value is transformed according to the provided function. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@mapValues[C]%28f:B=%3EC%29:scala.collection.Map[A,C]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ratesAndPreds.map( (User,Product,Predicted Rating) => (User,(Product,Predicted Rating) )
             .groupByKey()
             .map( (user,x) => (user,f(x) , g(x))
```

where f(x) transforms x (which is in the form (product1,rate1,product2,rate2...) ) to List(product1,product2...),

And g(x) transforms x to the rate you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If i am understanding correctly, what you have shown would give one rating to the whole group of products right ? I want to be able to have (u1,p1,r1),(u1,p2,r2),(u1,p3,r3) sorted by the ratings.